# Function call error when pressing a keyboard key (WxWidgets)

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, keyboard, wxwidgets

There is an application on WxWidgets:
[enter image description here](https://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/1162794d1593403649)

The same function is called in the code by two ways:

1. By pressing buttons in the application
2. By pressing keyboard buttons

Both methods call the same function with the same parameters, but an error occurs when using the keyboard:[enter image description here](https://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/1162795d1593403816)

Both calls the Enter () function

```cpp
void FrameApp::Enter(const char* value)
{
    if (value == "1")
    {
        BUFER.append("1");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "2")
    {
        BUFER.append("2");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "3")
    {
        BUFER.append("3");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "4")
    {
        BUFER.append("4");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "5")
    {
        BUFER.append("5");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "6")
    {
        BUFER.append("6");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "7")
    {
        BUFER.append("7");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "8")
    {
        BUFER.append("8");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "9")
    {
        BUFER.append("9");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "0")
    {
        BUFER.append("0");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == ",")
    {
        BUFER.append(",");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
}
```

And depending on the pressed key, it updates the variable storing text for output. And updates the text field using the function:

```cpp
void FrameApp::CalcEditUpdate(std::string bufer)
{
    calcEdit->SetValue(bufer);
}
```

---

All code:

```cpp
#include "../inc/FrameApp.h"
 
FrameApp::FrameApp(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize & size) : wxFrame((wxFrame*)NULL, -1, title, pos, size)
{
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
 
    calcEdit = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(-1, 60), wxTE_READONLY | wxTE_RIGHT | wxBORDER_RAISED);
    calcEdit->SetFont(wxFont(25, wxFONTFAMILY_ROMAN, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, wxT("Bodoni MT")));
    mainSizer->Add(calcEdit, 0, wxEXPAND);
 
    wxStaticLine* calcEditBorder = new wxStaticLine(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLI_HORIZONTAL);
    mainSizer->Add(calcEditBorder, 0, wxEXPAND | wxBOTTOM, 5);
 
    wxBoxSizer* row1Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* btn7 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("7"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn7->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row1Sizer->Add(btn7, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn8 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("8"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn8->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row1Sizer->Add(btn8, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn9 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("9"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn9->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row1Sizer->Add(btn9, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    mainSizer->Add(row1Sizer, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    
 
    wxBoxSizer* row2Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* btn4 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("4"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn4->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row2Sizer->Add(btn4, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn5 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("5"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn5->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row2Sizer->Add(btn5, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn6 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("6"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn6->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row2Sizer->Add(btn6, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    mainSizer->Add(row2Sizer, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
 
    wxBoxSizer* row3Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* btn1 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("1"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn1->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row3Sizer->Add(btn1, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn2 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("2"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn2->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row3Sizer->Add(btn2, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn3 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("3"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn3->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row3Sizer->Add(btn3, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    mainSizer->Add(row3Sizer, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
 
    wxBoxSizer* row4Sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* btnPM = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("+/-"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btnPM->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row4Sizer->Add(btnPM, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btn0 = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT("0"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btn0->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row4Sizer->Add(btn0, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    wxButton* btnD = new wxButton((wxWindow*)this, wxID_ANY, wxT(","), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    btnD->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
    row4Sizer->Add(btnD, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
    mainSizer->Add(row4Sizer, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 2);
 
    SetSizer(mainSizer);
}
 
void FrameApp::btnOnClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxButton* btn = (wxButton*)event.GetEventObject();
 
    if (btn->GetLabel() == "1")
    {
        Enter("1");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "2")
    {
        Enter("2");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "3")
    {
        Enter("3");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "4")
    {
        Enter("4");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "5")
    {
        Enter("5");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "6")
    {
        Enter("6");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "7")
    {
        Enter("7");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "8")
    {
        Enter("8");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "9")
    {
        Enter("9");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == "0")
    {
        Enter("0");
    }
    else if (btn->GetLabel() == ",")
    {
        Enter(",");
    }
}
 
void FrameApp::OnKeyDown(wxKeyEvent& event)
{
    switch ( event.GetKeyCode() )
    {
    case WXK_NUMPAD1:
        Enter("1");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD2:
        Enter("2");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD3:
        Enter("3");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD4:
        Enter("4");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD5:
        Enter("5");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD6:
        Enter("6");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD7:
        Enter("7");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD8:
        Enter("8");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD9:
        Enter("9");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD0:
        Enter("0");
        break;
    case WXK_NUMPAD_SEPARATOR:
        Enter(",");
        break;
    }
}
 
void FrameApp::Enter(const char* value)
{
    if (value == "1")
    {
        BUFER.append("1");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "2")
    {
        BUFER.append("2");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "3")
    {
        BUFER.append("3");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "4")
    {
        BUFER.append("4");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "5")
    {
        BUFER.append("5");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "6")
    {
        BUFER.append("6");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "7")
    {
        BUFER.append("7");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "8")
    {
        BUFER.append("8");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "9")
    {
        BUFER.append("9");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == "0")
    {
        BUFER.append("0");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
    else if (value == ",")
    {
        BUFER.append(",");
        CalcEditUpdate(BUFER);
    }
}
 
void FrameApp::CalcEditUpdate(std::string bufer)
{
    calcEdit->SetValue(bufer);
}
```

What can cause this behavior when calling through the keyboard?
The error itself appears on a call to the CalcEditUpdate () function.

---

In constructor of FrameApp i bind a btnOnClick() like this:

```cpp
btn7->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(FrameApp::btnOnClick), NULL, this);
```

In main.cpp i connect a handlers of onKeyDown() to App:

```cpp
#include "main.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

bool App::OnInit()
{
    FrameApp* frame = new FrameApp(wxT("Calc"), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 550));
    frame->SetSizeHints(wxSize(400, 550), wxSize(400, 550));
    frame->Show(true);

    this->Connect(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, wxKeyEventHandler(FrameApp::OnKeyDown));
    return true;
}
```

---

**Headers** with all others code of app

FrameApp.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include <wx/statline.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class FrameApp : public wxFrame
{
public:
    string BUFER;

    wxTextCtrl* calcEdit;

    FrameApp(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    void btnOnClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnKeyDown(wxKeyEvent& event);
    void Enter(const char* value);
    void FrameApp::CalcEditUpdate(std::string bufer)
};
```

main.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include "inc/FrameApp.h"

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit();
};
```

Comment: I am not going to follow links to a website I've never heard of.  Please provide details of the error as plain text.

Comment: When the keyboard button is pressed, function "void FrameApp :: CalcEditUpdate (std :: string bufer)" throws an error: "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
this-> calcEdit was nullptr. ". But when press the on-screen button, the same function is called with the same parameters, but without error

Comment: The shown code looks correct, so the problem must be in the code you don't show. How do you bind your `onBtnClick()` and `OnKeyDown()` handlers?

Comment: @VZ. I Bind headers in constructor of FrameApp for every button, and in main.cpp for keydown. I insert code in the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily see the difference between your 2 `Connect()` calls: you specify the object to call the method on correctly for `btnOnClick`, but not for `OnKeyDown`, so you end up calling the latter, which is a member of (incredibly confusingly named) `FrameApp` (which is not any kind of `App` at all) on your `App` object.

You can, of course, just fix the problem by providing the correct parameters to the `Connect()` call but the right thing to do is not use this deprecated since 10+ years function and use `Bind()`, which would catch errors like this at compile-time, e.g.

```
frame->Bind(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, &FrameApp::OnKeyDown, frame);
```